# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^2}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx$ step-by-step solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematica-online

I am trying to solve the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)^2}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx,$$
for $\eta \in R$.

For example if $\eta=1$, the [site](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bexp%5C%2840%29-Power%5B%5C%2840%29x-1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C1%2Bexp%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-inf%2Cinf%7D%5D) gives that the integral equals 0.51, but I don't understand how it is evaluated. I have read that it gives the solution step-by-step but not for this example. The same holds if I use the application. Could you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's clear that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(x-1)^2}}{1+e^{x}}\,dx$$ is done numerically by W|A. Therefore, its step-by-step calculation makes a little sense.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 evaluates `Integrate[Exp[-(x - 1)^2]/(1 + Exp[x]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity} ]` to `((-1 + 2 E^(1/4)) Sqrt[\[Pi]])/(2 E)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean when you say "is done numerically by W|A". Can you suggest me a reference for understanding the computation of this integral?

Comment: `NIntegrate[Exp[-(x-1)^2]/(1+Exp[x]),{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` produces `0.511223`. The method used by `NIntegrate` is know-how of WRInc.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know it.  Using the command "Integrate" now I get the result that @Ulrich Neumann said. Is there a way using "Integrate" for a step-by-step calculation? I used  Integrate[Exp[-(x - 1)^2]/(1 + Exp[x]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, PodStates -> {"Input__Show steps"}], but it is wrong.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann for clarity I want to point out that `V12` also performs the same integral with the same output.

Comment: @Anastasia your words are confusing me a bit. Are you trying to solve the integral for $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$ or see the steps for $\eta=1$?

Comment: I want to find the integral for $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$. However, when I use the command Integrate[Exp[-(x - a)^2]/(1 + Exp[x]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] it returns the integral and not the solution (I perhaps I am doing sth wrong). For this reason, I assume that $\eta=1$ trying to understand the steps and then I could generalize the solution.

Comment: You wrote: "I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean when you say 'is done numerically by W|A'." Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you don't understand the difference between symbolic and numerical solutions for integrals. A symbolic solution is what you're looking for. A numerical solution, by contrast, doesn't require solving the integral. It's instead generated by numerically calculating the area under the function between the limits. Since it doesn't involve determining a symbolic solution, there's no symbolic step-by-step solution to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The internal algorithms used by Mathematica for integration do not generally lend themselves to step-by-step description.

This integral cannot be done exactly; however, it can be done exactly for at least a limited number of specific values.

```
pts = {#, int = Integrate[E^(-(x - #)^2)/(1 + E^x), 
         {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], int // N} & /@ {-1, 0, 1, 2};

Grid[Prepend[pts, 
  Style[#, Bold] & /@ {η, 
    HoldForm[Integrate[E^(-(x - η)^2)/(1 + E^x), 
        {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]], "value"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Consequently, a numeric technique is needed in general.

```
intN[η_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[E^(-(x - η)^2)/(1 + E^x), 
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Plot[intN[η], {η, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> {Style[η, 14], None},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pts[[All, {1, 3}]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noticed that integral tends to 0 at infinity and to some positive number at - infinity.

Comment: thank you very much  for your help!

Comment: @user64494, that positive number seem to be $\sqrt \pi$.